# What does it mean by 'argument error: invalid index : Nothing type of nothing'

Tags: julia

I am getting an error in Julia. I don't know why I am getting this.

I am trying to implement diffusion Monte Carlo for a system. I have written the algorithm but am getting errors. Here is my code written in Julia below:

```
N_0=100
N_max=400
t_max=1000
del_t=0.01
x_min=-20
x_max=20
n_b=200

function VH(x)
    return -1/x
end

pos=zeros(Float64,N_max,5)
for i=1:N_max
    pos[i,1]=i
    if i<=N_0
        pos[i,2]=1
        pos[i,5]=1
    end
end
EnH=zeros(Float64,2*100*t_max+1)
t=0
a=1
while t<=2*t_max
    for i=1:N_max
        if pos[i,2]==1
            pos[i,3]=pos[i,3]+sqrt(del_t)*rand(Normal(0,1))
            pos[i,4]=pos[i,4]+sqrt(del_t)*rand(Normal(0,1))
            pos[i,5]=pos[i,5]+sqrt(del_t)*rand(Normal(0,1))
        end
    end
    N0=length(findall(pos[:,2].==1))
    E1=0
    for i=1:N_max
        if pos[i,2]==1
            r=sqrt(pos[i,3]^2+pos[i,4]^2+pos[i,5]^2)
            E1+=VH(r)/N0
        end
    end
    E=E1-(1/del_t)*log(N0/N_0)
    if t>t_max
        EnH[a]=E
    end
    for i=1:N_max
        if pos[i,2]==1
            r=(pos[i,3]^2+pos[i,4]^2+pos[i,5]^2)^(0.5)
            w=exp(-(VH(r)-E)*del_t)
            mn=min(floor(Int,w+rand()),3)
            if mn==0
                pos[i,2]=0
            elseif(mn==2)
                D=indexin(0,pos[:,2])
                pos[D[1],2]=1
                pos[D[1],3]=pos[i,3]
                pos[D[1],4]=pos[i,4]
                pos[D[1],5]=pos[i,5]
            elseif(mn==3)
                D1=indexin(0,pos[:,2])
                pos[D1[1],2]=1
                pos[D1[1],3]=pos[i,3]
                pos[D1[1],4]=pos[i,4]
                pos[D1[1],5]=pos[i,5]
                D2=indexin(0,pos[:,2])
                pos[D2[1],2]=1
                pos[D2[1],3]=pos[i,3]
                pos[D2[1],4]=pos[i,4]
                pos[D2[1],5]=pos[i,5]
            end
        end
    end
    N1=length(findall(pos[:,2].==1))
    t+=del_t
    a+=1
    if N1>N_max
        break
    end
end
```

And the error is the following:

```
ArgumentError: invalid index: nothing of type Nothing

Stacktrace:
 [1] to_index(i::Nothing)
   @ Base.indices.jl:300
 [2] to_index(A::Matrix{Float64}, i::Nothing)
   @ Base.indices.jl:277
 [3] to_indices
   @ .\indices.jl:333 [inlined]
 [4] to_indices
@.indices.jl:324 [inlined]
 [5] setindex!(::MatrixFloat64, ::Int64, ::Nothing, ::Int64)
   @ Base.abstractarray.jl:1344
 [6] top-level scope
   @ .\In[4]:47
```

From the error message, I didn't find the line causing the error. Is there any way to find out?

```
for k=1:2
    j=1
    while j<=N_max
        if pos[j,2]==0
            pos[j,2]=1
            pos[j,3]=pos[i,3]
            pos[j,4]=pos[i,4]
            pos[j,5]=pos[i,5]
            break
        end
        j+=1
    end
end
```

When I use the above instead of the inbuilt function **indexin()**, the algorithm works perfectly. My goal is to find out the row index of first two 0's in 2nd column (for mn = 3). What could be the reason for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such things are easiest degugged with Infiltrator.jl. Your problem is that sometimes you are looking for a value using `indexin` that is not present in `pos[:, 2]` vector.

When you write `@infiltrate condition` you will switch to infiltration mode when the `condition` is `true` (without condition you go to infiltration unconditionally).

Here is the code that allows you to investigate the issue:

```
using Distributions
using Infiltrator

N_0 = 100
N_max = 400
t_max = 1000
del_t = 0.01
x_min = -20
x_max = 20
n_b = 200

function VH(x)
    return -1 / x
end

pos = zeros(Float64, N_max, 5)
for i = 1:N_max
    pos[i, 1] = i
    if i <= N_0
        pos[i, 2] = 1
        pos[i, 5] = 1
    end
end
EnH = zeros(Float64, 2 * 100 * t_max + 1)
t = 0
a = 1

while t<=2*t_max
    for i=1:N_max
        if pos[i,2]==1
            pos[i,3]=pos[i,3]+sqrt(del_t)*rand(Normal(0,1))
            pos[i,4]=pos[i,4]+sqrt(del_t)*rand(Normal(0,1))
            pos[i,5]=pos[i,5]+sqrt(del_t)*rand(Normal(0,1))
        end
    end
    N0=length(findall(pos[:,2].==1))
    E1=0
    for i=1:N_max
        if pos[i,2]==1
            r=sqrt(pos[i,3]^2+pos[i,4]^2+pos[i,5]^2)
            E1+=VH(r)/N0
        end
    end
    E=E1-(1/del_t)*log(N0/N_0)
    if t>t_max
        EnH[a]=E
    end
    for i=1:N_max
        if pos[i,2]==1
            r=(pos[i,3]^2+pos[i,4]^2+pos[i,5]^2)^(0.5)
            w=exp(-(VH(r)-E)*del_t)
            mn=min(floor(Int,w+rand()),3)
            if mn==0
                pos[i,2]=0
            elseif(mn==2)
                D=indexin(0,pos[:,2])
                @infiltrate isnothing(D[1])
                pos[D[1],2]=1
                pos[D[1],3]=pos[i,3]
                pos[D[1],4]=pos[i,4]
                pos[D[1],5]=pos[i,5]
            elseif(mn==3)
                D1=indexin(0,pos[:,2])
                @infiltrate isnothing(D1[1])
                pos[D1[1], 2] = 1
                pos[D1[1],3]=pos[i,3]
                pos[D1[1],4]=pos[i,4]
                pos[D1[1],5]=pos[i,5]
                D2=indexin(0,pos[:,2])
                @infiltrate isnothing(D2[1])
                pos[D2[1], 2] = 1
                pos[D2[1],3]=pos[i,3]
                pos[D2[1],4]=pos[i,4]
                pos[D2[1],5]=pos[i,5]
            end
        end
    end
    N1=length(findall(pos[:,2].==1))
    global t += del_t
    global a += 1
    if N1>N_max
        break
    end
end
```

(note that I almost did not change your code, although it could be improved for performance a lot; the only change I made is by adding `global` to lines `t += del_t` and `a += 1` as you are updating global variables inside a loop).

Your code is randomized, so you might get a different result to what I show below (but the general schema will be the same). When run this code I get:

```
Infiltrating top-level scope

infil> D2
0-dimensional Array{Union{Nothing, Int64}, 0}:
nothing
```

I manually checked the `D2` variable and see that it is set to `nothing` in its first entry.

So let us inspect further:

```
infil> unique(pos[:, 2])
1-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
```

which shows that your `pos[:, 2]` has `1.0` entry everywhere and you were looking for `0.0`. Let us reassure us that this is the problem:

```
infil> indexin(0,pos[:,2])
0-dimensional Array{Union{Nothing, Int64}, 0}:
nothing
```

Indeed it is.

Let us maybe also check at what time this happened:

```
infil> t
483.3499999997054
```

So:

1. It seems that your algorithm is incorrect (I have not looked into its logic) - probably you need to change your code.
2. You know (I hope my explanation was clear) how to debug your Julia code.

Note that the condition of the `@infiltrate` operation can be anywhere else where you would want to inspect your code. For more details see https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Infiltrator.jl.

Comment: I edited my question. If I use a for loop and while loop instead of indexin(), the algorithm is working perfectly. My goal is to find the row index first 0 of 2nd column. Can recheck once and what could be the reason for this?
Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you ask about precisely. But if you ask what is the reason that `for` loop works while `indexin` fails it is the following. If `indexin` returns `nothing` in the first position you should skip the operations that follow (this is what you do in your for loop - if for no index you find `0` you just do not do anything).